# jQuery .append() not rendering html entity

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-entities

I have a variable with html in it like this:

```
var html = '<div>Hello, you&#39;re awesome!</div>';
```

I want to append it to an element `$("body").append(html)` for some reason it's not decoding the HTML Entity. I tried `$("body").append($(html));` and that didn't work. My text is stuck inside the element and I can't individually put it together.

Is there any way to append html with a text-based entity inside it into another element, and have the html entity render on the page?

I've read a bunch of posts on stackoverflow reguarding html entities and it seems that none of them include the html & text within a variable like this.

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/zF4Va/1/

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ruALs/

Comment: Ah my text was `&amp;#39;`! I should have checked outside my environment and confirmed. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var html = $('<div>Hello, you&#39;re awesome!</div>');
$("body").append(html)
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/zrCum/)

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add .get(0) to the end.

Answer (score 2):

It could be possible that your page did not finish loading while the jQuery code was trying to append the content. Try:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
  var html = '<div>Hello, you&#39;re awesome!</div>';
  $('body').append(html)
});
```

And I would suggest using single quotations only unless you need to use escaped characters.